# Try to add UIFont to XCode project

Tags: objective-c, uifont

I try to add OpenSans-Regular.ttf to my Xcode project:

1)I add the file into the project.

[image]

[image]

2) add font in plist.

[image]

3)check if the file add to Bundle resources
[image]

[image]

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];


UILabel *myLable = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 50)];

myLable.text = @"TEST RR";

[myLable setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Regular" size:30]];

myLable.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

myLable.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

[self.view addSubview:myLable];

NSLog (@"Font families: %@", myLable.font.familyName);

 }
```

and the font not work !

[image]

Comment: Some of the fonts not support the exact size you want so try with font size 24 or 36 for this "OpenSans-Regular"

Comment: Did you install that font in font book of mac?

Comment: Yes ,  I think I fix this , I change the font name without space Between the letters And It Start to work (-:

Comment: Just use @"OpenSans" for regular font

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @keyur bhalodiya you have to use the font name like @"OpenSnas" for regular fonts

Create a custom label subclass of UILabel 'CustomFontLabel'

in CustomFontLabel.h define property to set the font name

```
@interface CustomFontLabel : UILabel

@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable NSString *overrideFontName;

@end
```

In the .m file add the below code

```
- (void)setOverrideFontName:(NSString *)overrideFontName

{
    if (![_overrideFontName isEqualToString:overrideFontName])
    {
        _overrideFontName = overrideFontName;
        self.font = self.font;
    }
}

- (void)setFont:(UIFont *)font
{
    NSString *overrideFontName = self.overrideFontName;
    if (overrideFontName != nil)
    {
        font = [UIFont fontWithName:overrideFontName size:font.pointSize];
    }

    [super setFont:font];
}
```

With the IBInspectable you can even set the overrideFontName property from Storyboard also. Don't forget to set the label class to CustomLabel in the storyboard. Try that and let me know, if it's working or not..!